Thread in a Pod not consuming from Kafka Partition
We have 40 Partitions in Kafka Topic, and we are running 20 Pods with 2 Threads each. During peak data rate time, we are seeing that some partitions show high Kafka lag.
One more point to note is that this is not specific to 1 Pod, but we are seeing it happening with more than 1 Pods, where 1 Thread in Pod P1 and 1 Thread in Pod P2 are not able to consume from the Kafka Partitions assigned to them.
Our CPU Usage and Memory usages have not reached to Limits we have set and is well below even during the peak data rate when we see the Kafka Lag coming in.
Also, processing delay(Time when data is sent/sinked from job - Time when data reach the job ) is coming close 100mS which means that procession the data is not at all the problem.
We are using K-Streams in Sprint Boot application running on Kubernetes.
Need some guidance on root causing the issue.

Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  It seems very possible with the setup you've shown that some replicas have 3 partitions assigned and some with only 1; if each worker runs 2 tasks concurrently but otherwise blocks, that in turn would lead to some of the partitions backing up.

Having a minimal reproducible example for this case will not help for root causing the problem I have posted. The problem is more of understanding what could go wrong and based on experiences of folks here, they can easily classify this problem and help in resolution.
